# Purpose of ugettext inside of Models

Tags: python, django, gettext

In plenty of Django tuts, and everywhere online, people will create fields such as the below within a model class:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class MyModel(models.Model)
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        _('Created'),
        auto_now_add=True
    )
```

I understand what `ugettext` is doing but I don't understand why it's being applied to, in this example, 'Created'. Why not just write:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Furthermore, is 'Created' referring to something that's been defined somewhere? In this example, I don't see it existing in `forms.py`, nor is it passed through in `views.py`. So, whatever it is, it's existing solely within this model - or so I think.

Comment: Another example, that might shine light on where this confusion arose. I am looking at models.py for pybbm [link](https://github.com/hovel/pybbm/blob/master/pybb/models.py) and lines 226-228 have `body = models.TextField(_('Message'))` and `body_html = models.TextField(_('HTML version'))` and `body_text = models.TextField(_('Text version'))`. What does the text (message, html vers, and text vers) accomplish in these lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it's just as simple as if you don't define that string, it'll get used to identify the field in a `ModelForm`. If you then use various languages on your site, that field wouldn't have a translated string associated with it.

So you can define a form nice and easy, in `forms.py`;

```
from django import forms

from .models import MyModel


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    MyForm is a nice a simple ModelForm using
    labels from MyModel.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['created', ]

# views.py
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

from .forms import MyForm


class MyObjCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = MyForm
```

By adding that `ugettext` string, it would get pulled in to the message catalog which can then be translated. At least this makes sense from my experience of translations.

Check out the docs, especially this about the `class Meta` of a model;
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#model-verbose-names-values

Answer (score 0):

it's needed for translation purpose. If you don't provide the `verbose_name` Django will labelize the field name, but will never be able to translate it. see here for doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/